# Grabing the units for a material

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I am using Selenium to grab material information from a website. I can't figure out how to grab some stand alone text in the div tags without grabbing the other sibling div information. What is the proper XPATH to grab the unit quantity from the following html?

```
<div class="pricingReg xh-highlight" itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" xpath="1">
    <span id="ajaxPrice" class="pReg" itemprop="price" content="29.98">
        <span class="price__currency">$</span><span class="price__dollars" style="">29</span>
        <span class="price__cents">98</span>
    </span>
        /each
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">
</div>
```

So far I've tried:

```
try:
  element = "//div[@class='pricingReg']"
  el = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, element)
  el_text = el.get_attribute("innerText")
  print(el_text)
  purchase_unit_label = re.search('^[a-zA-Z]*$', el_text)
  print('Purchase Unit Label =' + purchase_unit_label)
except NoSuchElementException:
  print('Purchase Unit Label NoSuchElementException')
```

This is giving me the following output in the console:

```
Name: 3/8 in. x 100 ft. Diamond-Braid Poly Rope
Description: 3/8 in. x 100 ft. Diamond Braid Poly Rope is designed for maximum strength and durability. It's made with a polypropylene jacket covering a mixed synthetic core. Common uses include: securing equipment, making a shelter, using as a rescue line, lifting objects with a pulley and tying down loads and using while camping or boating. Do not use for overhead lifting.
Image: https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/9b89db7a-5ecd-41a0-8ebb-1924ce3176aa/svn/multi-everbilt-rope-14156-64_1000.jpg
cost_per_purchase_unit = 998.0

                    $998
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/my_user/PycharmProjects/scraper/hd_scraper_materials.py", line 200, in <module>
print('Purchase Unit Label =' + purchase_unit_label)
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType
```

You can see how I am getting %998 in the example above when I am actually hoping to get 'each'.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to extract through `grab the unit quantity`?

Comment: I'm trying to grab the /each but I only want to grab 'each'. For example, another item might have 'square feet' I need to grab that for that item.

Answer (score 0):

well, this divs have attributes and values on it so... with css (assuming it due to the css-selector tag on the question):

selectors for...
price__currency:

```
.prince__currency
```

price__dollars:

```
.price__dollars
```

price__cents:

```
.price__cents
```

itemprop attribute:

```
link[itemprop] or meta[itemprop]
```

i never worked with selenium but i can write jquery for you to extrapolate:

```js
$("input[value='Hot Fuzz']" ).next().text( "Hot Fuzz" );

alert ($("input[name='news']").attr('customAttribute'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="Hot Fuzz">
    <span>name?</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="Cold Fusion">
    <span>value?</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="Evil Plans">
    <span>value?</span>
  </label>
  <label>
     <input name="news" type="text" customAttribute="quantity:98" />
  </label>
</div>
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: I added some more to the initial post to clarify. I'm still having this issue.